# Azure service bus queue error in the logic app

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I am trying to use Service Bus Queue send action in my logic app which sends a message to a queue. When the logic app runs the action returns this error:

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "message": "Cannot use a trigger on an entity with auto-forwarding enabled.",
  "source": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

Although at the time of creation of the queue I didn't set the auto-forwarding enabled. Any help?

Comment: If you inspect the queue using SBExplorer, is forwarding enabled by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you do not have partitioning turned on for the Service Bus Queue.
It is default on when creating queues in the "new" azure portal.

Got the same misleading error.

Comment: I am wondering if that was off by default in the past, I swear for older topics I have created I didn't un-check that.  Regardless, thank you was pulling my hair out.

Comment: Yes it was off by default in the old portal. I was in the hair pulling business myself there for a while :-)

Answer (score 0):

Auto-Forwarding is a feature in Service Bus Queues and Topics, by enabling it (setting a destination Queue or Topic), the messages sent to the Queue or Topic will be forwarded to the Destination entity.

You cannot use such entities in Logic App Send or Receive message action. You cannot set this property using Azure Portal. You can do it using tools like Service Bus Explorer or Serverless360 or using this [.Net client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/).

Look here for more details about [Auto-Forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were trigger errors pointing towards the issue, which was to do with the enforcement of sessions being enabled on the named queue. Creating another queue and removing the requirement for sessions, resolved the issue.

The error message at first was not clear as it only stated the following:

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "message": "Cannot use a trigger on 'transfwopartition' entity with auto-forwarding enabled.\r\nclientRequestId: b62228df-830d-4564-a1f9-6727102fe2f0",
  "source": "servicebus-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Auto-forwarding was off and was never enabled on my queue. Same applied to partitions (not sure whether the use partitions would make a difference, but checked this as per the previous comment on here).

However, if you look at the trigger errors, you will gain more detailed error messages, like the one below indicating it was an issue with sessions. Thus, the solution is to use a queue that does not enforce sessions or provide a session ID (for actions that support this parameter).

```
"body": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver. TrackingId:265012a9-ffe8-4982-85c9-2799ec29b69b_G23_B34, SystemTracker:servicebusmiti:Queue:transfwopartition, Timestamp:2018-12-19T22:29:17\r\nclientRequestId: 872039fa-d310-47f5-a11e-50335ae5f128",
    "source": "servicebus-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the property "supportOrdering" is set to true on the service bus topic (in ARM, not visible in the portal) in the standard tier, this will cause issues with sending messages from a logic app to Service Bus topic. You can check this in resources.azure.com and then going to the service bus topic to see this property.

[image: Image of settings]

Answer (score -3):

Check if Session is enabled on the Queue.